# Is it possible to get Blazemeter like report in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to generate a report in JMeter exactly like Blazemeter. Do we have any listener in JMeter or any plugin. I did search on google but didn't find the exact solution. If anyone has idea then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Taurus tool](https://gettaurus.org/), it provides possibilities to:

1. Run existing [.jmx script](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File)
2. Get [online interactive report in your browser](https://gettaurus.org/docs/BlazemeterReporter/)
3. [Load existing .jtl results file to BlazeMeter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ResultsLoader/#Existing-Results-Loader)

There is [The Complete Taurus Course](https://www.blazemeter.com/university) in the BlazeMeter University.

Alternative option would be using [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) to store your test results in [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) and visualize it using [Grafana](https://grafana.com/). There are several existing [JMeter dashboards](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/?search=jmeter), you might find one of them covering your needs or use it as a basis for your customizations.